Runtime Broker - Consuming lots of memory
I have developed a UWP app years ago to download and store files and sync data from a service of mine.
This application has been stable and working without issues for long time, however a recent change in the behaviour of the solution has meant it's almost continually streaming data from the service and a side effect of that means the runtime broker is consuming so much memory the system grinding to a halt, even stopping the traffic doesn't free the memory.
Is there any way I can debug what is happening with this RuntimeBroker or understand why this is happening?


Where is it "storing the files"? What is it storing? Is it storing or "retrying"? What are the time stamps? How big are the files? How big "should" they be? How many "should" there be?

Most the files it's storing are less the 1MB and some can be up to 10MB. All files are being stored on a local hard disk, ( Usually on the C:, but it's configurable).
There is usally around 16,000 files

You've described the "expected"; not what is currently happening.

Could you please provide more details to further analyze this problem.
How is the broker called? Is it just opening and maintaining a permanent stream, or is it opening and closing the stream?
What language is used? Where are the files stored? Is this running on a background thread or the UI thread? The file usage seems to be in the background, you can use a lower-level file API instead of going through the broker.

@GerrySchmitz what I describe is what is happening.

@JunjieZhu-MSFT - The isn't called by my software, it appears to be started by default on all UWP applications. If I can prevent it from starting please advise. What API's are you referring to?

It is recommended that you use lower-level APIs to read and write file, such as System.IO.File class or win32 API WriteFile(fileapi.h) ReadFile (fileapi.h). Please note that UWP only have default permissions only for its application data folder. To write elsewhere they'll need permissions (via manifest, picker, etc), you can get CreateFile2FromApp (or related *FromApp) methods to get a HANDLE with the app's granted UWP permissions.
